# Parsing html for windows 8 metro style application using C#, XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

My application should parse the html and load the contents into the list box. I am able to get the html via webclient but got stuck parsing it.
I heard of Htmlagilitypack and Fizzler but couldn't find any tutorials or examples on their usage.

I want some help in grabbing "first_content" and "second_content" into a list box from the html document shown below.

```
<html>
<body> 
<div>
<section>
<article>
   <header> 
       <hgroup> 
           <h1> 
              first_content
           </h1>
       </hgroup>
   </header> 
   <ul> 
        <li> 
           second_content
        </li>
   </ul>
</article> 
</section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For the "what did you try?" series, did you try with a raw XmlReader?

Comment: I sort of admire [the effort](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14756076/edit/05cfc11a-9a36-4fde-90da-8422f82b9f94) you put into formatting your question, but please read the [faq on formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), it's much easier done in the proper way.

Answer (score 3):

HtmlAgilityPack is the way to go, I've been using it in WCF, Windows Phone and now WinRt with total success, for a tutorial check [this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020001935/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011211-1.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the blog. But the article in the blog is not working for winrt. 
For instance, "var document = webGet.Load(url);" webGet doesn't have "Load" method to load the URL. Instead I used, webGet.LoadFromWebAsync("http://www.something.com") which is working. 
For, document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//meta"); I am getting red underline for "DocumentNode". I couldn't proceed. 
Can you help me with a tutorial that just points to metro style app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath.  For example ...

```
var html = "<html><body><div><section><article><header><hgroup><h1>first_content</h1></hgroup></header><ul><li>second_content</li></ul></article> </section></div></body></html>";
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(html);
var txt1 = doc.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div/section/article/header/hgroup/h1").InnerText;
var txt2 = doc.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div/section/article/ul/li").InnerText;
```